# React react-redux redux-persist performance issue

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-redux, redux-persist

I am very new to react and redux at the same time.

I am building this app that has a questionnaire made up of a few hundreds of questions. I want to persist the answers to the questions in real time so that the user can come back and continue any time.

The problem is that each dispatch of persisting the answer takes more than 2 seconds when I render 300 elements.

This is my component that I use for each of the questions (items).

```
import React from 'react';
import {setAnswer} from "../actions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Container,Row,Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Radio, RadioGroup,FormControlLabel} from '@material-ui/core'


class FormItem extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            answer: this.props.answers[this.props.item.nr] ? this.props.answers[this.props.item.nr] : 0
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        this.setState({
            answer:target.value
        })
        this.props.setAnswer(this.props.item.nr,target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Row className={"item-row" + (this.state.answer != 0 ? " answered" : "")}>
                <Col md={"5"}><div>{this.props.item.text}</div></Col>
                <Col md={"7"}>
                    <RadioGroup name={"item"+this.props.answers.nr} value={this.state.answer} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col className={"text-center"}><FormControlLabel value="1" control={<Radio color="primary" />} /></Col>
                            <Col className={"text-center"}><FormControlLabel value="2" control={<Radio color="primary" />} /></Col>
                            <Col className={"text-center"}><FormControlLabel value="3" control={<Radio color="primary" />} /></Col>
                            <Col className={"text-center"}><FormControlLabel value="4" control={<Radio color="primary" />} /></Col>
                            <Col className={"text-center"}><FormControlLabel value="5" control={<Radio color="primary" />} /></Col>
                        </Row>
                    </RadioGroup>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        answers : state.answers
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
    return {
        setAnswer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps())(FormItem);
```

The problem is that if I render the whole 300 items on the page at the same time, dispatching the setAnswer action on the radio change takes 2.5 seconds. If I render only 30 at a time, it works fairly well. Now, 300 is not a huge number so I am assuming that there is something that I am doing wrong since the performance is so much affected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take out the question part and put it in a pure component, there is a bit too much code to go through and don't know why you would duplicate redux state to local state but here is an example where question is a pure component (using React.memo) that gets a change handler passed that never changes (using React.useCallback) and the question (from state.items).

Because Question is a pure component it will only render when a prop is changed and only the item that is changing answer will change so only that Question is re rendered:

Here is the functional example

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 300;
const initialState = {
  items: new Array(NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
    .fill('')
    .reduce((result, _, id) => {
      result[id] = { id, answer: '' };
      return result;
    }, {}),
};
//action types
const CHANGE_ANSWER = 'CHANGE_ANSWER';
//action creators
const changeAnswer = (id, answer) => ({
  type: CHANGE_ANSWER,
  payload: { id, answer },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CHANGE_ANSWER) {
    const { id, answer } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      items: {
        ...state.items,
        [id]: { ...state.items[id], answer },
      },
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors (not even using reselect)
const selectItems = (state) => Object.values(state.items);
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      //middleware handling SET_NEXT action will
      //  dispatch removed and added for each item that
      //  has been removed or added
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
//*********************************************
//               End of set up code
//*********************************************

//make Question a pure component using React.memo
const Question = React.memo(function Question({
  changeQuestion,
  question: { id, answer },
}) {
  const r = React.useRef(0);
  r.current++;
  return (
    <li>
      {id} rendered {r.current}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={answer}
        onChange={(e) => changeQuestion(id, e.target.value)}
      />
    </li>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const questions = useSelector(selectItems);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    (id, val) => dispatch(changeAnswer(id, val)),
    [dispatch]
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {questions.map((question) => (
        <Question
          key={question.id}
          question={question}
          changeQuestion={onChange}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is the example with class components using PureComponent for Question:

```js
const { Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 300;
const initialState = {
  items: new Array(NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
    .fill('')
    .reduce((result, _, id) => {
      result[id] = { id, answer: '' };
      return result;
    }, {}),
};
//action types
const CHANGE_ANSWER = 'CHANGE_ANSWER';
//action creators
const changeAnswer = (id, answer) => ({
  type: CHANGE_ANSWER,
  payload: { id, answer },
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CHANGE_ANSWER) {
    const { id, answer } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      items: {
        ...state.items,
        [id]: { ...state.items[id], answer },
      },
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors (not even using reselect)
const selectItems = (state) => Object.values(state.items);
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      //middleware handling SET_NEXT action will
      //  dispatch removed and added for each item that
      //  has been removed or added
      () => (next) => (action) => next(action)
    )
  )
);
//make question pure component by extending React.PureComponent
class Question extends React.PureComponent {
  rendered = 0;
  render() {
    const {
      changeQuestion,
      question: { id, answer },
    } = this.props;
    this.rendered++;
    return (
      <li>
        {id} rendered {this.rendered}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={answer}
          onChange={(e) =>
            changeQuestion(id, e.target.value)
          }
        />
      </li>
    );
  }
}
class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const questions = this.props.questions;
    return (
      <ul>
        {questions.map((question) => (
          <Question
            key={question.id}
            question={question}
            changeQuestion={this.props.changeAnswer}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
const App = ReactRedux.connect(
  (state) => ({
    questions: selectItems(state),
  }),
  { changeAnswer }
)(AppComponent);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply! 

Your component Question is the same as my component FormItem, and I tried to update the redux state through a prop that is set in the parent component but the performance is the same.

The main difference I see in your code is that you are using functions components instead of class components like I am. So do you think this is causing the performance issues? I still can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @VladDogarescu Updated the question with class component example, you can extend PureComponent in Question.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out finally. I was getting a bad performance because I was injecting with mapStateToProps all the answers into every Item instead of setting as a prop just the particular answer that was concerning that Item. Thank you for your effort! If you write this in an answer I can mark it as correct, since this was the specific thing affecting performance and can help someone else.